# read an JSON object with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, codeigniter

so i have a question, i have a json object, but i cant read with javascript

this is my code

```
    $.ajax({
          url:'index.php/usuarios/getUsuarioById', 
          type: 'POST',
          data:{ usuario_id: usuario_id }, 
          dataType: 'Json',
          complete: function(data){

              alert(data.Nombre);
              alert(data['Nombre']);


          }

        });
```

the nav only shows undefined, if i make a parse shows me another error, i dont need make a parse because im sure that the response its an Json object this is my code on de server side PHP

public function getUsuarioById(){

```
    //echo $this->input->post('usuario_id'); exit;
    $result = $this->usuarios_model->getUsuarioById($this->input->post('usuario_id'));
    echo json_encode($result);



}
```

Comment: Can i see the data `console.log(data)`?

Comment: what does console.log(data) inside your complete() show you?

Comment: Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "{"Id_Usuario":9,"Nombre":"alejandrina","apellido_p…9e062aa5e4a390b0a572ac0d2c0220","Tipo_usuario":2}", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}

Comment: Try `data.responseText.Nombre`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
alert(data.Nombre);
alert(data['Nombre']);
```

use:

```
console.log(data);
```

This way, you'll know how the response data is structured in order to access it's attributes correctly.

or try:

```
console.log(data[0].Nombre)
```

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: thats the result with the console log Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "{"Id_Usuario":9,"Nombre":"alejandrina","apellido_p…9e062aa5e4a390b0a572ac0d2c0220","Tipo_usuario":2}", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}

Comment: @NovEskEduard, then you can access your data with var response = data.responseJSON, var Nombre = response.Nombre;

Answer (score 0):

hey guys finally i fix my problem, like you can see my JSON object have it an null value, then when i trying to make a parse chrome sows me error

responseText: "{"Id_Usuario":9,"Nombre":"alejandrina", null: 9e062aa5e4a390b0a572ac0d2c02‌​20","Tipo_usuario":2}", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}

I could finally solve it this way

```
 $.post(
            'index.php/usuarios/getUsuarioById', 
            { usuario_id: usuario_id }, 
            'Json'
           ).done(function(data){

              var usuario = JSON.parse(data);
              alert(usuario.Nombre);

           });
```